# "ModuleNotFound" for a pip install of tensorflow to Anaconda on Mac OS

Tags: macos, tensorflow, pip, anaconda

After a successful install in an *Anaconda* environment, on *Mac OS* using the recommended [Tensorflow install](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac), trying it --

```
import tensorflow
```

returns "ModuleNotFoundError"

Answer (score 0):

The tensorflow install page recommends installing under Anaconda on the Mac by

```
(tensorflow)$ pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade <URL of the tensor flow package>
```

See [Installing with Anaconda](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac) from www.tensorflow.org. There's a problem if your Anaconda environment disagrees with where `pip` places the install. Anaconda wants a different root directory for Python's `site-packages`, which can arise since the Anaconda install conventionally sits in one's home directory, and the native OSX Python is under /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/.

To check where pip did the install, do

```
pip show tensorflow
```

To see where Anaconda expects it, activate the Anaconda environment, look for its `site-packages` in the `sys.path` variable:

```
~ $ python
Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, ...
>>> import os; sys.path
['', '/Users/me/Documents/p2', ... '/Users/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages', ...]
```

Note that the `PYTHONPATH` shell variable entry is pre-pended to your `sys.path`. A preferable solution to modifying your `PYTHONPATH`, is to direct `pip` to use the pip target option to install it in the place where Anaconda expects it:

```
$ sudo -H pip install --target='/Users/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages' --ignore-installed --upgrade  <URL of the tensor flow package>
```

If you get write errors for ~/Library/Caches/pip/http, you can avoid them by using `sudo -H`.

Comment: If you install with sudo, doesn't that set the owner of a directory in your home directory to root? That seems like it could cause problems in the future... In other words, why are you suggesting to use sudo at all? If the target and the cache are both in `~`, why use sudo?

Comment: @darthbith - sudo -H is innocuous.  Otherwise the command throws this error: 
     The directory '/Users/me/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.`

Comment: I know that `-H` is to fix the cache problem with sudo. I'm asking, why use sudo at all? You're installing into a user-owned directory, so why do you need to install as the root user?